# Webpack, asp.net core, docker: building webpack with dotnet debug or release build

Tags: docker, build, webpack, .net-core

I've got an asp.net core application, similar to what `aspnetcore-spa` provides. Webpack is set up for both `--env.prod` and `--env.dev` and it's integrated via `JavaScriptServices`.

Building and running the application from Visual Studio 2015 seems to work fine*. Debug builds with `Development` environment run fine on Kestrel - the webpack middleware (re)builds the client app and hot module replacement works well (albeit a bit slow - most likely due to the hardcoded referenced assets it has to copy).

*However, the vendor bundle is never rebuilt, nor would the `--env.prod` webpack build ever be run. I assume that this all works (even in the examples) merely because a version of the files is committed to the repository.

Running `dotnet run` or `dotnet build` is not enough, because this does not touch webpack. I could provide some scripts in the `package.json` for this, I don't know how (or if) I could embed this in the build in Visual Studio - plus, I feel a bit dirty using `npm` instead of `dotnet` directly.

This whole issue is also tied into my problems of building a debugable docker image. I guess I could run webpack in the container and copy all sources there - but this still leaves the question:

How can I integrate webpack builds into Visual Studio (or even better, `dotnet`)?

Comment: If you find a solution I'd certainly like to hear about it.

Comment: likewise. I have found this to be of value in the meantime: https://medium.com/@andyccs/webpack-and-docker-for-development-and-deployment-ae0e73243db4#.m1rqo3r1g

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

## We've solved this via our process and use `npm` scripts

- Building, deploying etc. are handled via npm scripts
- Whenever somebody checks out a branch, pulls commits or added new vendor-dependencies, they run `npm run build-webpack-dev-vendor`, which is an npm script that runs `npm-run webpack --env.dev --config ./config/webpack.config.vendor.js`
- Docker builds are run from npm scripts as well

The build output from webpack is put into the `wwwroot` directory and its entire content is gitignored (except `.gitignore`).

### Webpack scripts

These scripts are used for any or all webpack builds.

```
"build-webpack-dev": "npm run build-webpack-dev-vendor && npm run build-webpack-dev-app",
"build-webpack-dev-vendor": "npm-run webpack --config ./config/webpack.config.vendor.js --env.dev",
"build-webpack-dev-app": "npm-run webpack --env.dev --display-modules",
"build-webpack-prod": "npm run build-webpack-prod-vendor && npm run build-webpack-prod-app",
"build-webpack-prod-vendor": "npm-run webpack --config ./config/webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod",
"build-webpack-prod-app": "npm-run webpack --env.prod --display-modules",
```

Our configuration does not discern between prod and dev vendor builds.
Note: requires `npm-run` to be installed.

### Docker scripts

These scripts are used to build and publish our docker images.
We have *fast* variants of the scripts, which speed publishing (no rebuild, no extra login).

```
"docker-build-prod": "dotnet publish --configuration Release && docker build bin\\Release\\netcoreapp1.1\\publish -t company/product:tag --no-cache",
"docker-publish-prod": "npm run docker-build-prod && docker login && docker push company/product:tag",
"docker-publish-prod-fast": "docker push company/product:tag",
"docker-login": "docker login",
```

Developers *should* check the build output, if there are any bundles in the app which should be moved to the vendor bundle (hence the use of `--display-modules` in the webpack build).

### Supplementary scripts

Finally, not everyone in our team was using Visual Studio (designers for example). We provided scripts for them and some more general purpose scripts.
The *fast* variants skip `npm install`, building of the vendor bundle and restoring of nuget packages.

```
"start-dev": "npm install && npm run build-webpack-dev && dotnet restore && dotnet run --configuration Debug --environment \"Development\"",
"start-dev-fast": "dotnet run --configuration Debug --environment \"Development\"",
"start-prod": "npm install && npm run build-webpack-prod && dotnet restore && dotnet run --configuration Release --environment \"Production\"",
"start-prod-fast": "npm run build-webpack-prod-app && dotnet run --configuration Release --environment \"Production\"",
```

Finally, for good measure

```
"refresh": "npm install && dotnet restore"
```

I hope that helps and I'm open for suggestions on how to improve this :)